# indexOfObjectIdenticalTo: - Getting junk value

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

```
NSString *yes0 = @"yes";
NSString *yes1 = @"YES";
NSString *yes2 = @"Yes";
NSString *yes3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yes1];

NSArray *yesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"yes", @"YES", @"Yes", @"YES", nil];

NSArray *yesArray1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:yes0, yes1, yes2, yes3, nil];
NSUInteger index;


index = [yesArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:yes3];
NSLog(@"\nindex : %d",  index); // 1st Output


index = [yesArray1 indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:yes3];
NSLog(@"\nindex : %d",  index); // 2nd Output
```

- 1st Output

Output i receive is: **"2013-07-18 16:42:04.896 Collections - Arrays[2778:f803] index : 2147483647"**

- 2nd Output

Output i receive is: **"2013-07-18 16:42:04.896 Collections - Arrays[2778:f803] index : 3"**

I get confused due to the outputs i receive. Kindly explain me the process why i get the junk value during the output 1. According me, both arrays are identical with objects. Then why this junk value.

Also having a question:

> According to apple, **indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:** returns - The lowest
>   index whose corresponding array value is identical to anObject.

Upto my understanding, in yesArray1 -  ***yes1*** is same as ***yes3***. My expecting value of `output 2` is 1 which gets contradict with the actual printed value (3). Also please let me understand it properly why it is printing 3 rather than 1.

Comment: *equal* and *identical* are not the same. equal objects are a-like, but not necessarily the same objects. identically means that they are the same object. In Objecive-C this means they have the same pointer.

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's not a "junk value", it's the `NSNotFound` constant.

The first `index` is not found because `yes3` is not in `yesArray` (it's only in `yesArray1`) – note that `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` checks for pointer identity, not object equality (unlike `indexOfObject:`).

Comment: Hi OMZ, as u say it checks with the pointer array. For the pointer array it has the reference as the memory. If i am right, then also the memory address is getting different. So i'm blank and confused of this method. Let me get it more accurate how it works.

Answer (score 1):

`indexOfObjectIdenticalTo` checks for pointer equality, not object equality. `2147483647` isn't a junk value, it's the value of `NSNotFound` (which is the defined result if no index is found).

Answer (score 0):

```
indexOfObjectIdenticalTo : checks for pointer equality

indexOfObject: checks Object equality.

Good Luck !!!
```